# stick to bottom footer and body toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I have a "stick to bottom" footer that means that even if the content of the page is very small the footer will be on the bottom of the screen. If the content is bigger, the footer will be at the end of the footer.

simply done with:

```
html {
position: relative;
height: 100%;
}

body {
height: 100%;
font-size: 14px;
padding-top: 42px;
}


toggling:

$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: anchor.offset().top}, speed);
```

Now my page toggling is ruined as I can't do it, becasuse the body is 100% all the time, anyway to bypass that?

Comment: So where is your code show us something what have you tried so far using fiddle.

Comment: I found this is a common problem so I removed it